# #1005 - Can't create table 'classorganizer.turma' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I keep getting the following error: **#1005 - Can't create table 'classorganizer.turma' (errno: 150) (Detalhes...) **

from trying to create the table Turma although I've double checked all the foreign keys cases in that class. Does anyone knows whats wrong?

Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario(
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
nome VARCHAR(30),
senha INTEGER NOT NULL,
dataCadastro DATE NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pkUsu PRIMARY KEY(email),
CONSTRAINT formatoEmail CHECK(email LIKE '%@%.%')
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Professor(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
ranking INTEGER DEFAULT 3,
usuario VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_prof PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_usu FOREIGN KEY (usuario) REFERENCES Usuario(email) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT limites_rank CHECK(ranking >0 AND ranking<6)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Materia(
codigo VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
nro_turmas INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
nro_cred_aula INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
nro_cred_trab INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
prioridade INTEGER DEFAULT 3,
usuario VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_prof PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_usu FOREIGN KEY (usuario) REFERENCES Usuario(email) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT limites_prio CHECK(prioridade >0 AND prioridade<6)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Turma(
nro INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
prioridade INTEGER DEFAULT 3,
materia VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
professor INTEGER NOT NULL,
usuario VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_turma PRIMARY KEY (nro),
CONSTRAINT fk_mat FOREIGN KEY (materia) REFERENCES Materia(codigo) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_prof FOREIGN KEY (professor) REFERENCES Professor(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_usu FOREIGN KEY (usuario) REFERENCES Usuario(email) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT limites_prio CHECK(prioridade >0 AND prioridade<6)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of errors.

1. `CONSTRAINT pk_prof PRIMARY KEY (id)`. **`id` column doesn't exist in  table `Materia`**.
2. **Constraint names (pk_prof, fk_usu) are already used in `Professor` table**. You have used it in both `Materia` and `Turma` table. 
   Correct it by choosing unique names. Easiest way is to omit the name. MySQL handle it.
3. **`codigo` column of `Materia`  is referenced in `Turma` table, But its not a **key***.*
4. `professor` **column of `Turma` is defined to be `NOT NULL`. But you used `ON DELETE SET NULL`.**

Comment: Thank you Shiplu, for your time and patience. I'm still a begginner but will make sure I pay a closer look at my future codes regarding those things. take care.